# Raw .net framework libraries?

Tags: .net, vb.net, frameworks

I need to access the raw .NET framework libraries ( such as System ) and etc. All of the libraries that are required by .NET programs to run. Is there a specific place on my harddrive that I can find them all?

Comment: It might be wise to explain why you need to access them so we can answer your question better than just passing a folder to you.

Comment: Indeed.  Not counting on the ngen-ed assemblies and the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit versions of some of the assemblies that contain native code is going to be raw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.NET 2.0 (32-bit) C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
.NET 2.0 (64-bit) C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
.NET 4.0 (32-bit) C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
.NET 4.0 (64-bit) C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

The .NET 3.0 extra assemblies are in various places under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET, just look around for them.

I would also wonder why you would want to directly access these assemblies.  The only real use I can think of is using the runtime compiler to load specific assemblies manually, but you can usually just specify the assembly filename because they are almost all in the GAC.